# ASP.NET Web API Routing Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

This is the default Router that I've modified:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{addParam}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, addParam = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

This is the Controller:

```
public class ReviewCycleController : ApiController
{

    private MrdSearchServices _mrss = new MrdSearchServices();


    // GET api/reviewcycle
    public IQueryable<MrdReviewCycle> GetReviewCycles()
    {

        return _mrss.GetAllReviewCycles();
    }


    // GET api/reviewcycle/Active
    public MrdReviewCycle GetReviewCycle(String is_active)
    {
        if (!is_active.ToLower().Equals("active"))
        {
            string url = new Uri(Request.RequestUri, "/api/ReviewCycle/Active").ToString();
            var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(string.Format("No Review Cycle with State of '{0}' could be found. The only acceptable value is 'Active'. Request should be made to {1}.", is_active, url)),
                ReasonPhrase = "Review Cycle Not Found!"
            };
            throw new HttpResponseException(resp);
        }

        return _mrss.GetActiveReviewCycle();
    }
}
```

But when I call either: `http://localhost:2515/api/ReviewCycle/asdf` or `http://localhost:2515/api/ReviewCycle` I don't get the results expected. What I get for both is the result of `return _mrss.GetActiveReviewCycle();`.

What the heck am I doing wrong?

Thanks
Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public MrdReviewCycle GetReviewCycle(String is_active)
```

should be probably be:

```
public MrdReviewCycle GetReviewCycle(String addParam)
```

Also please note that you can have only 1 optional parameter in a route and this parameter has to be the last one. In your route definition you have 2 optional parameters (`{id}` and `{addParam}`) which is not possible.

Also the calling url should be (once you make the `{id}` parameter non-optional):

```
http://localhost:2515/api/ReviewCycle/123/active
```

Another potential problem that I see with your code is that in your route there's no `{action}` token meaning that you should use the standard HTTP verbs as action names and not `GetReviewCycle`. Should be `Get` and since you have used the GET verb on the `ReviewCycle` controller, it is this action that will be invoked.